# Error when setting plt.axis('off') with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting following error when I'm trying to save my ndarray with matplotlib, with plt.axis('off'):

```
  File "classifier/classifier_tester.py", line 25, in remove_outliers
    plt.axes('off')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 923, in axes
    return gcf().add_axes(rect, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1135, in add_axes
    if not np.isfinite(rect).all():
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I have never seen this error, what could be the problem?
The dtype of my ndarrays is float64.

For context, the error comes in this function:

```
def remove_outliers(image, save_dir, counter):
    from scipy import ndimage
    from skimage.morphology import watershed
    distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image)
    markers = ndimage.label(image)[0]
    labels = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=image)
    print(type(distance))
    print(distance.dtype)
    if len(np.unique(labels)) > 2:
        new = np.where(labels == 1, 1, 0)
        plt.imshow(distance)
        plt.axes('off')
        plt.savefig(save_dir + 'outliers/distance{}.pdf'.format(counter), format='pdf')
        plt.close()
        plt.imshow(labels)
        plt.title(str(np.unique(labels)))
        # plt.axes('off')
        plt.savefig(save_dir + 'outliers/labels{}.pdf'.format(counter), format='pdf')
        plt.close()
        plt.imshow(new, cmap = 'gray')
        # plt.axes('off')
        plt.savefig(save_dir + 'outliers/output{}.pdf'.format(counter), format='pdf')
        plt.close()
        plt.imshow(image, cmap = 'gray')
        # plt.axes('off')
        plt.savefig(save_dir + 'outliers/input{}.pdf'.format(counter), format='pdf')
        plt.close()
        return new
    else: return image
```

Edit: also I have no problem saving the images with the axis.

Comment: Have you tried using `False` instead of `'off'`?

Comment: Using `'False'` instead of `'off'` gives me the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing [`axis`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) with [`axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html).

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.axis('off')
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
>>> plt.axes('off')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```